# Deleting a tableView cell SWIFT

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

How can I delete a table view cell with Swift?  I am using parse also. It would be great if someone can tell me how to make an action sheet asking, "Are you sure you want to delete?"  If not that's okay.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import UIKit

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate,
PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

    var noteObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {

        }else {
            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
            self.fetchAllObjects()
        }
    }

    func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore() {

        var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Note")

        query.fromLocalDatastore()
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {

                var temp: NSArray = objects!;  NSArray.self

                self.noteObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }else {

            }
        }
    }

    func fetchAllObjects() {

        PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

        var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Note")

        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {

                PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: { (success, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
                    }
                })
            }else {

                println(error!.userInfo)

            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return self.noteObjects.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MasterTableViewCell

        var object: PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        cell.masterTitleLabel?.text = object["title"] as? String
        cell.masterTextLabel?.text = object["text"] as? String

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editNote", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var upcoming: AddNoteTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddNoteTableViewController

        if (segue.identifier == "editNote") {

            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

            var object: PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

            upcoming.object = object

            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `commitEditingStyle` method of tableview :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Note", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this note?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Destructive, handler: {
            (alert:UIAlertAction!) in
            //****//
             your code to delete item from parse.
            // ***//
             //And then remove object from tableview
             self.noteObjects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
             self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

`Delete` button will be visible on swiping left specific table cell
Hope this will help!